# Deploying using Octo.exe on Mono fails with "The resource you requested was not found"

Tags: mono, octopus-deploy

I’m trying to use octo.exe on Linux via mono.

For the most part it appears to work, but when I try to deploy it keeps failing with:

> The resource you requested was not found.
>
> Error from Octopus server.
>
> (HTTP 404 NotFound) Exit code: -7

I am calling it like so:

```
mono tools/Octo.exe create-release --project MyApp --version 123.4 --deployto develop --server https://octopus.mycompany.com/ --apiKey ******* --ignoreexisting --package=MyPackage:123.4
```

If I drop the `mono` and run this command on Windows (using .NET Framework) this all works fine, but with mono I’m stuck with "resource not found” errors.

Octo.exe with mono appears to be working in most other ways. It can create a release successfully for example, it's just breaking when it tries to deploy.

Here is the version outputs:

> Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version 4.13.13
>
> Handshaking with Octopus server: https://octopus.mycompany.com/
>
> Handshake successful.
>
> Octopus version: 3.12.5; API version: 3.0.0

I have tried stripping away all the command line options and also split it into separate `create-release`, `deploy-release` which only reinforced it’s the deploy part that always fails. Communication with server seems fine as it’s able to handshake, view and create releases etc. I have also tried with different permissions including full Administrator (still fails) so seems not to be a permission thing.

Any ideas?

> Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
>
> Mono JIT compiler version 5.12.0.226 (tarball Thu May  3 09:48:32 UTC 2018)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in any version of the Octopus Tools released after May 11 2017
https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusClients/pull/166

How I diagnosed the problem:

By using the `--debug` flag I discovered octo.exe, when running on mono, is trying to do `GET https://octopus.mycompany.com/file:///api/releases/Releases-80268` but when run on .NET Framework its doing `https://octopus.mycompany.com/api/releases/Releases-80269`.

This was clearly what was causing the 404 - the root cause presumably being a bug in mono that was exposed when Octo.exe is building the URI.