# Unable to create release in Octopus Deploy using GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, octopus-deploy

I am trying to set up GitHub Actions to create a release in Octopus deploy using the following steps:

```
- name: Install Octopus CLI 
  uses: OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action@v3.0.0
  with:
    version: '*'

- name: Deploy 
  run: |
    octopus release create --project ${{ env.OCTOPUS_PROJECT }} --channel ${{ env.OCTOPUS_CHANNEL}} --release-notes 'Release me' --package-version '1.0.675-feature-27ddcf53143'
```

I want to use the new octopus cli - https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api/cli/octopus-release-create.

These are the environment variables defined:

```
env:
  OCTOPUS_CHANNEL: 'Feature'
  OCTOPUS_URL: ${{ secrets.OCTOPUS_SERVER }}
  OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.OCTOPUS_API_KEY }}
  OCTOPUS_SPACE: 'SPACE-NAME-HERE'
  OCTOPUS_PROJECT: 'PROJECT-NAME-HERE'
```

If I go to the Octopus UI and manually create a release, selecting channel 'Feature' and version '1.0.675-feature-27ddcf53143' of my packages, the release is created successfully.

However, when I try with the above code in GitHub Actions I get:

> Octopus API error: The resource you requested was not found. []
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Running the following command works just fine:

```
octopus release list
```

For sake of completeness, here is the full github action workflow:

```
name: CI

on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  CI:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, small]
    env:
      OCTOPUS_CHANNEL: 'Feature'
      OCTOPUS_URL: ${{ secrets.OCTOPUS_SERVER }}
      OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.OCTOPUS_API_KEY }}
      OCTOPUS_SPACE: 'SPACE-NAME-HERE'
      OCTOPUS_PROJECT: 'PROJECT-NAME-HERE'
    steps:

    - name: Install Octopus CLI 
      uses: OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action@v3.0.0
      with:
        version: '*'

    - name: Deploy 
      run: |
        octopus release list --project ${{ env.OCTOPUS_PROJECT }}
        octopus release create --project ${{ env.OCTOPUS_PROJECT }} --channel ${{ env.OCTOPUS_CHANNEL }} --release-notes 'Release'
```

and the secrets:

*EDIT* - cant add picture of secrets as imgur is blocked my company. I verified that OCTOPUS_SERVER and OCTOPUS_API_KEY exists as secrets

What am I doing wrong? What is missing to make this work in GitHub Actions?

Comment: Looks like the action you're using is to install the CLI. However, those env vars do not seem to be related to the CLI. A search on their [docs](https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api/cli) site led to their official [GitHub Actions](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/build-servers/github-actions) and those env vars are listed there. See https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/build-servers/github-actions#deploy-release and https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/build-servers/github-actions#deploy-release-tenanted.

Comment: For the CLI, there are flags available to pass those values e.g. `--apiKey`. See https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api/octopus-cli/create-release.

Comment: @Azeem I am not interested in using those actions - I want to use the CLI which requires those env variables to be set. I will update the question. See https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action and https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api/cli

Comment: Right. Does the CLI work locally after setting the env vars?

Comment: Can you please combine your workflow showing the exact sequence of the `env` and the steps along with the `runs-on` and the `environment` (if applicable)? Please do include a snapshot of the secrets page as well.

Comment: Unfortunately my workplace does not allow installation of the CLI on my work pc - I am trying to get it whitelisted. And Octopus is running on a server which is only available internally. Will try to get the information you are requesting when I get to my work pc again.

Comment: Sure, no worries. Take you time. Just want to confirm whether the same configuration via env vars works locally or not; and, whether the secrets are defined properly (along with the environment if needed).

Comment: @Azeem updated with the info you requested. Unfortunately imgur is blocked by my company, but I triple-checked that the secrets referenced actually exists

Comment: You can try using all the command line flags to pass those values instead of env vars. Please try that. As you're using a self-hosted runner, if you have access to that you can directly try and run the CLI commands there with env vars to test it.

Comment: I tested your scenario and it's working fine for me. See [these workflow runs](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/workflows/ci-octopus-cli-test.yml). I stumbled upon these threads (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165170/deploying-using-octo-exe-on-mono-fails-with-the-resource-you-requested-was-not) and [this](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/7060)), Are you using the new CLI with older releases?

Comment: Also, I observed that using https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action is slow (it takes ~3 minutes) whereas installing it with `curl` (see [this](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/cli?tab=readme-ov-file#linux--macos---curl-script)) takes only a second.

Comment: @Azeem I changed my syntax to match yours from your test runs and still same error. I also suspect that it's because I am running an older version of Octopus (2019.11.1), so I reached out to Octopus support team. If they confirm that it's due to this old version, I'll come back here and provide an update - I suspect that it will be sometime in mid-January as they are closed for holidays now.
When I use the install-octopus-cli-action it takes seconds not minutes, so not too slow for me. Thank you for your efforts so far!

Comment: The syntax wasn't the issue. You can experiment with the free trial of octopus and its CLI from your local machine. The only error which is similar to yours is with `octopus release list --project=INVALID_PROJECT` and the output is `cannot find the item`. Anyways, the internal API mismatch seems to be the issue here between old octopus deploy and its new CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with Octopus support on this for some time, we reached the conclusion that the error is due to me using an older version of Octopus server (2019.11.1) together with the new octopus cli (in Go).

Thank you to all of you for your assistance